# How can I lay out three labels one after another with two at the end in Xamarin.Forms XAML

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to layout but it's not working.  Here is what I have:

```
<Grid">
   <Label Text="ABC"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
   <Label Text="DEF"  HorizontalOptions="End"/>
   <Label Text="GHI"  HorizontalOptions="End" />
</Grid>
```

This gives me the following where DEF appears on top of GHI

```
ABC                              DGHIEF
```

Can someone give me advice on how I can achieve this layout:

```
ABC                              DEF GHI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Text="ABC"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="DEF"  HorizontalOptions="End"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2"  Text="GHI"  HorizontalOptions="Start" />
</Grid>
```

You separate the content by columns and use the Horizontal Option to place the items where you need.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: What's the difference between the * and Auto?  Also did you mean to have the last Horizontaloptions set to Start ?

Comment: When I try this I notice it works but if the value of the third column is nothing then the DEF shifts to the far right.  What I would like is all the DEF columns to line up vertically.

Comment: `*` will try to use all the available space while `Auto` will use only what the content requires. More about this here : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/

Comment: So in this case if the value of column 2 is nothing can I still have a width there?

Comment: Then change `Auto` for a size. This will force the Grid to reserve the space even though the content is empty. Try with 60